# TCP/IP connection between ubuntu (C) and windows (Java)

Tags: java, c, sockets, windows-7, ubuntu-12.04

I'm trying to establish a TCP/IP communication between a server in C running in ubuntu 12.04 and a client in Java (EJS) running in Win7. The server is a thread of a greater program, so it's created with pthread. When I try this with both server and client in ubuntu (localhost) everything goes fine, all the functionalities work great and I'm making further progress to configure my GUI. But when I use the client in my notebook with win7 I can't make a connection even if I define the host ip and the port ( /etc/hosts + /etc/services and C:\WINNT\system32\drivers\etc\hosts + C:\WINNT\system32\drivers\etc\services)

I think I'm missing something and I don't know what. It's the first time I develop a server-client socket and my progress is thanks to some examples found in internet. Here are some extract of my code, the relevant parts I think:

Server in C (Ubuntu):

```
//Initialization, headers and other threads
.
.
.

void * servidor(void *arg)
{
int Socket_Servidor;
int Socket_Cliente;
struct sockaddr_in Direccion;
struct servent *Puerto;
socklen_t Longitud_Cliente;
struct sockaddr Cliente;
struct timespec now,period;
int dummy,i,j;
unsigned long overruns_r;
int ejecutado =1;
int terminado =1;

int A[1];                    
int B[2];
double C[2];

   period.tv_sec=0;
   period.tv_nsec=PERIOD3;

   clock_gettime    ( CLOCK_REALTIME, &now);
   now.tv_nsec=now.tv_nsec+PERIOD3;
   dummy=pthread_make_periodic_np (pthread_self(), &now,&period);
   switch(dummy){
     case 0 : 
      break;
     case ESRCH: 
    printf("thread is invalid \n"); 
    pthread_exit ((void *)-1);  
      break;
     case ETIMEDOUT : 
    printf("the start time has already passed\n"); 
    pthread_exit ((void *)-1); 
      break;
     default : 
    printf(" output value not defined \n"); 
        pthread_exit ((void *)-1); 
}

Socket_Servidor = socket (AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);  //Obtener el descriptor del socket
if (Socket_Servidor == -1) printf("No se puede crear el socket\n");

Puerto = getservbyname ("cpp_java", "tcp"); //Obtener el numero del servicio 25557
if (Puerto == NULL) printf("BIND fallido\n");

Direccion.sin_family = AF_INET; //Tipo de conexion
Direccion.sin_port = Puerto->s_port; //Servicio a atender
Direccion.sin_addr.s_addr =INADDR_ANY; //DirecciÃ³n del cliente (cualquiera)

if (bind (Socket_Servidor,(struct sockaddr *)&Direccion,sizeof(Direccion))==-1)
{
     printf("BIND fallido\n");
     close (Socket_Servidor);
}


if (listen (Socket_Servidor, 1) == -1) //Atender llamadas, un cliente en espera
{
     printf("Fallo en 'listen'\n");
 close (Socket_Servidor);
}

//Aceptar la conexion
Longitud_Cliente = sizeof (Cliente);
Socket_Cliente = accept (Socket_Servidor, &Cliente, &Longitud_Cliente);
if (Socket_Cliente == -1) printf ("No se puede abrir socket de cliente\n");

while(ejec){

// Some actions of the server
.
.
.
```

Java client (win7)

```
// Custom section of EJS
public boolean conectar () {
try { 

    javaSocket = new Socket();//crea socket sin conexion
    ((Socket)javaSocket).connect(new InetSocketAddress("10.5.3.60",25557),3000);// 3 seg de timeout en la conexion inicial
    ((Socket)javaSocket).setSoTimeout (8000);// 8 segundos de timeout durante la conexion

    in = new DataInputStream(((Socket)javaSocket).getInputStream());
    out = new DataOutputStream(((Socket)javaSocket).getOutputStream());
    ((Socket)javaSocket).setTcpNoDelay (true);
    if (javaSocket != null) { 
        connected = true;
        _play();
    } 
}catch (java.net.UnknownHostException e) {
    lastErrorMsg = "Method startTCP: Unknown host." + " " + e.getMessage();            
}catch (SocketTimeoutException e2){
    lastErrorMsg = "Method startTCP: Timeout at connect.";            
}catch (java.io.IOException e) {
    lastErrorMsg = "Method startTCP: Input/output exception." + " " + e.getMessage();
}catch (java.lang.Exception e2){
    lastErrorMsg = "Method startTCP: No connection to host." + " " + e2.getMessage();           
}    
return connected;   
}
```

Any help will be much appreciated. Thank you very much for your time and replies in advance

Thanks for your comments and answers. I tried `lsof -Pni | grep LISTEN` and I got this:

```
cupsd   717  root    8u  IPv6  10478   0t0  TCP [::1]:631 (LISTEN)
cupsd   717  root    9u  IPv4  10479   0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:631 (LISTEN)
dnsmasq 1097 nobody  5u  IPv4  11512   0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:53 (LISTEN)
ser1    1998 root    3r  IPv4  12659   0t0  TCP *:25557 (LISTEN)
```

where ser1 is my server program. I also disabled the firewall in windows but I still don't have connection.
Thank you.

Comment: On the Ubuntu server side, as root, list the open sockets with listeners: `lsof -Pni | grep LISTEN` and make sure you can find your server process in the list. Post here the line(s) of output for your server program. I suspect that the server process is only listening on local (to the server) ports, not on your ethernet interface.

Comment: I don't see any data transfer in your code. What exception/error are you getting? Can you post the _play() (the relevant part) function?

Comment: I edited my question and added the results of lsof -Pni | grep LISTEN, what should I check next?

Answer (score 1):

Hi after reading your server code I can suggest you to set the port for server socket as follows :

```
   Direccion.sin_port = htons(25557) // the port have mentioned in java client socket.
```

Answer (score 0):

As you said,"It's the first time I develop a server-client socket and my progress"

Turn off the firewall of Windows and try again. Because I don't know much about Java, that's the only thing I can advise.